# Search for a pattern in string Js

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to code something, I tried but that doesn't work, so I have a string and I want my code to search for a pattern in it. For example, if 'hello, this is a test' I want to search in this string the 'etet' pattern and the first iteration. In that case, it will be:
'h**e**llo, **t**his is a t**e**s**t**' and after, the other characters will be replaced by '-' like so: '-**e**-----**t**----------**e**-**t**'. I tried regex :

```
string = string.replace(/[^eEtT]/g, '-')
```

but it gives every letters, and not the only pattern.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: This `console.log('hello, this is a test'.replace(/[^eEtT]/g, '-'));` gives `-e-----t---------te-t` Is that not expected?

Comment: There's the  't' in the middle that shouldn't be here

Comment: @Drakeee0909 Why shouldn't it be there? You're replacing everything except `e` and `t`. So `t` should stay.

Comment: yeah, with this code yes, but for what I want, it shouldn't be there

Comment: It's not clear what you really want.

Comment: I think I see it. You want to first replace everything between `e` and the next `t` with `-`, then everything between that `t` and the next `e`, then repeat this again. I don't think you can do this with a single regexp.

Comment: I want the code to search for the etet pattern (doesn't matter if it's uppercase or lowercase), it searches in the string 'e' then 't' that's after the 'e' in the string, and same for the two others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups, first capturing `e` and then the next `t`
In the callback of replace, check if there is a capture group.

```
(e)[^t]*(t)|.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWGwre/1)

Replace with group 1 and group 2, and repeat adding `_` for the number of characters that matched in between.

```js
const regex = /(e)[^t]*(t)|./gi;
const s = "hello, this is a test.";
const result = s.replace(regex, (m, g1, g2) =>
  g1 ? g1 + "-".repeat(m.length - 2) + g2 : "-"
);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
/(^.*?)(e)(.*?)(t)(.*?)(e)(.*?)(t)(.*)/gm
```

`(^.*?)` matches the beginning of the string, containing 0 or more of any character, until it gets to...

`(e)` an e, then

`(.*?)` 0 or more of any character until it gets to

`(t)` a t.

Etc...

The groups matched for `hello-this-is-the-test` are:

```
0-1 h
1-2 e
2-6 llo-
6-7 t
7-16    his-is-th
16-17   e
17-18   -
18-19   t
19-22   est
```

https://regex101.com/r/FPRCT1/1